# Haskell maximumBy for Ord instances

Tags: haskell, max

I keep finding myself wanting a function for this, and I always need to implement it myself, but I feel like there must be a built-in for it.

Basically, what I want is sort of halfway between `maximum` and `maximumBy`.

`maximum` takes a list of `Ord` values and returns the maximum. This is O(n).

```
maximum :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
```

`maximumBy` takes a list of non-`Ord` values and a sort function that provides an ordering for them, and computes the maximum using that function. This is O(nlogn) (or whatever the complexity is for a sort).

```
maximumBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a
```

I want a `maximumBy` that takes a list of values of type `a` and a function that returns `Ord` values for `a` values, and computes the maximum `a` using the `Ord` values. This would be O(n) because it only needs to keep track of the maximum as it goes along. This is what that signature would be:

```
maximumBy' :: (Ord b) => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
```

And this is my rough implementation:

```
maximumBy' func list = foldl1' (\max i -> let (maxby, iby) = (func max, func i) in if iby > maxby then i else max) list
```

Is there such a function built-in, or perhaps an easy way to write this using existing built-ins?

Comment: `maximumBy` works in *O(n)*...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you make a claim that is wrong:

> `maximumBy` takes a list of non-Ord values and a sort function that provides an ordering for them, and computes the maximum using that function. This is *O(nlogn)*.

No sorting has to be done to calculate the maximum element. An ordering relation has to be *reflexive*, *anti-symmetric* and *transitive*, and therefore one can simply alsways hold the maximum thus far, and use the custom comparison to check whether the new item is greater.

Furthermore you can construct you `maximumBy'` function as:

```
maximumBy' f = maximumBy (compare `on` f)
```

Comment: Correct; however ``compare `on` f`` does have a significant performance penalty, because for every comparison `f` needs to be calculated on _both_ elements, i.e. you get twice as many calls to `f` than necessary.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. And excellent point @leftroundabout. I will take that in mind.

Comment: Use the Schawrtz...ian transform!

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yours is the Schwartzian transform to which I was referring.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is easily expressed using `Data.Ord.comparing`:

Instead of using your `maximumBy'` function:

```
maximumBy' head ["abc", "def", "geh"]
```

you can build a comparator with `comparing` and give that to the usual `maximumBy`:

```
maximumBy (comparing head) ["abc", "def", "geh"]
```

And as Willem Van Onsem says in another answer, you are incorrect to be concerned about the cost of `maximumBy`: it does not sort the list.

Answer (score 4):

That function is defined [the `tip-lib` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tip-lib-0.2.2/docs/Tip-Utils.html#v:maximumOn) as

```
maximumOn :: (Foldable f, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> b
```

The general idea has also been [adopted in recent `base`, with](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn)

```
sortOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Note that thanks to laziness, you can use

```
maximumOn :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> b
maximumOn f = head . sortOn f
```

and get the same asymptotic performance as a manual implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any built-in function that does what you want, but you can really simplify your implementation of `maximumBy'`.

You could use [`on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) for example:

```
import Data.Function (on)

maximumBy' :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> a
maximumBy' f = maximumBy (compare `on` f)
```

In fact, this definition is so simple you could use it as-is, without defining `maximumBy'` at all.